# Center <p> in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have some problem to center p inside a div.
I need some help!

Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end align-items-end mb-3 d-none d-sm-flex">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-white me-2 fw-bold">
    <p>THIS NEEDS TO BE CENTERED</p>
  </div>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-gold" href="">Booking!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the error here? Can you provide what's the current display and what's your expected result? Also what have you tried to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can center a p tag using multiple methods in bootstrap.

This is how you can center it with `text-center` according to the [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)

```html
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
```

Also if you want to center the paragraph vertically, you can use the `d-flex` and `align-items-center` classes. Here is an example:

```html
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center" style="height: 100vh;">
  <p class="text-center mx-auto">This paragraph will be centered vertically.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-center` class for its parent div. if you only need to center `<p>` place `text-center` class inside it.

```
<div class="navbar d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end align-items-end mb-3 d-none d-sm-flex">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-white me-2 fw-bold text-center">
    <p>THIS NEEDS TO BE CENTERED</p>
  </div>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-gold" href="">Booking!</a>
</div>
```

Read more:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/